# Autosizing form to stop controls from overlapping - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am currently designing a form for my business - but struggling to implement a feature.

The image below is of the bottom half of a form - I had to blur/remove quite a lot for data privacy reasons. There are two group boxes here (one on the left and the other on the right).

The blue area is a `tool strip`. The greyed out areas represent apps. The application itself is basically an app launcher that allows the users to add apps to the tool strip.

Right now I've set the `tools strip`'s `LayoutStyle` to `Flow` and the `AutoSize` to `False`

This means that when there are only enough apps to fill one row on the `tool strip`, it all looks fine, with some space between the bottom of the `GroupBoxes` and the top of the `tool strip`

However when I add enough apps that there needs to be two rows on the `tool strip`, the `tool strip` expands to two rows (represented in the image).

This is what I want, however as can be seen from the image, the `tool strip` now covers up part of the  `Groupboxes`.

So I think what I want is for the actual form to expand when the `tool strip` expands, maintaining an same distance between the bottoms of the `Groupboxes` and the top of the `tool strip`.

Can this be done simply by setting some properties, or is there a way to do this programatically?

[image]

Comment: So you want to keep the "tool strip expands to two rows" functionality?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to expand. I just want the form to change size as well so the tool strip doesn't overlap other controls. I posted an 'answer' below of something I've used for now which seems to work. Although it's not perfect.

Comment: Realised my Maths wasn't even close to write, so deleted it for now.

Comment: If you can afford the screen space to show the form in an expanded state for a two row toolstrip, why not just have it that way all the time (have a blank space at the form base so the expanded toolstrip covers nothing important)?

Comment: If you add a Panel to the form and set its Dock property to Fill then it will take up the space not occupied by the ToolStrip, resizing as necessary. You can then put your other controls in it and use Anchor and Dock properties to maintain the desired layout, perhaps incorporating a TableLayoutPanel. The TableLayoutPanel might replace the Panel completely for the right layout.

Comment: Set tool strip's Dock property to 'Bottom' and set the dock property of one GroupBox to "Left", and set the other to "Right", then you can resize form's height to avoid tool strip covering part of the Groupboxes when tool strip expands.

Comment: Thanks guys. I gave all of these suggestions a try, but got nothing to work yet :/